# cron job decides for itself if it wants to run

Tags: 18.04, bash, scripts, python, cron

I recently wrote a python script that reminds me via email if I need to move my car for the street sweeper mafia (and avoid a ticket). When I ran the script from the command line, it worked every time. So I added it to `crontab -e` and tested it, it worked if I reset the date, time, etc.

I decided to run the cron tab every hour just for debug purposes:

```
1 * * * * python3 /home/robert/scripts/parking-project.py
```

On the night last week when the python script should have triggered the email, I was ready for the reminder. Instead there was no action.

I researched several cronjob articles to see how I messed up, but they all reinforced my original implementation decisions.

Eventually I got distracted and started working on other projects, but then today, out of the blue, my cronjob started working exactly like I expected it to.

*more info*

- I had restarted the machine many times since implementing the job - so a reboot was not the answer.
- my clock was correct
- the script worked perfectly if you copied and pasted the command that was listed in crontab -e
- `journalctl -u cron.service` reported that there was never any attempt to run the cronjob
- internet access was not a factor

What could have made the cronjob suddenly decide to start working correctly?

Comment: Was your system, by chance, suspended/hibernated/off or simply logged off during the periods that the cronjobs did not run?

Comment: @user535733, yes, but  not always. There were plenty of times when it should have run when it was online but didn't. I don't think this was a factor, but thank you for jumping in.

Comment: wouldn't `1 * * * *` mean the first minute of every hour? Remember, the notation is MM HH, not HH MM. Some versions of cron also require a username such as `00 01 * * * root /home/robert/scripts/parking-project.py`. My server performs a bulk processing of security footage with a crontab, and it looks like this (ubuntu 16.04) `30 2   * * *   root    bash /mnt/array0/porch/process.sh`

Comment: @Minty OP said "run [...] every hour", so that line is OK. The user crontab edited using `crontab -e` doesn't require a username (those commands run as your user). The username is required in system crontab files (`/etc/cronatb`, `/etc/cron.d/*`).